# Recovering data from a hard drive which disappears from /dev upon reading data in a bad block

Tags: linux, macos, hard-drive, data-recovery, dd

I'm attempting to recover as much data as possible from a failed 750 GB hard drive which is connected via a USB 3 drive enclosure.

The drive itself has over 1500 bad blocks, detected by `badblocks` on Linux.

It mounts perfectly on my computer (running macOS 10.12), but when data from a corrupt block is read, the drive idles for a few seconds, disappears from `/dev`, and then reappears — as if someone had unplugged the USB cable and then quickly plugged it back in again.

The first bad block occurs about 136 GiB from the start of the disk, however this is not the only one. This is evidenced by output from `badblocks`, along with when both `dd` and `ddrescue` fail.

`dd` and `ddrescue` both fail as soon as they read data from a bad block, since the drive then disappears from `/dev`:

`dd if=/dev/rdisk3 of=image.img bs=16m`:

[image]

`ddrescue -v /dev/disk4 image.img logfile`:

[image]

Rerunning `ddrescue` after the initial termination with the same log file results in it immediately terminating and not advancing further.

Since I am able to traverse the filesystem and access some files normally, [I wrote a script](http://pastebin.com/hjZbFb7y) to determine which files are accessible and which aren't, so I can copy the known good files from the disk. However, this is slow, and I'm worried that it may damage the disk further.

Is there any tool similar to `dd` or `ddrescue` which can recover data from this drive, which just waits for the drive to remount instead of automatically quitting upon reading a bad block?

I'm able to use both macOS as well as Linux (Ubuntu), so solutions for either platform would work for me.

Comment: By "unmounts" you mean "disappears from `/dev`", not the `umount` command, right? I'm asking to avoid terminology confusion. I think `ddrescue` is supposed to continue its interrupted run when you invoke it with the same logfile. Maybe you can write a simple script that runs `ddrescue` after a while again and again – and see if it advances your progress. Another approach is to fabricate the initial logfile (based on the `badblocks` result) so `ddrescue` never touches problematic sectors. There is `ddrescuelog` tool that may help. Just an idea, I have never done it myself.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yes, by unmount, I mean that it disappears from `/dev` (and is sometimes assigned a new identifier upon remount). Rerunning `ddrescue` again results in immediate termination, it never advances further. I'll experiment with manipulating the log file to see if that yields any results.

Comment: But `badblocks` had no problems, right? Have you tried `ddrescue --direct` option?

Comment: If the USB-SATA bridge causes the "unmount", one solution is to take the drive out of the enclosure and connect it directly via SATA. (All USB closures I've seen so far have SATA drives inside them).

Comment: @Jack Greenhill: If my answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.

Comment: So if the drive disappears from /dev after trying to shred bad blocks and then never shows up again even after a reboot, there's nothing else I can do with it?

Answer (score 3):

> when data from a corrupt block is read, the drive idles for a few seconds, unmounts, and then remounts

I had the same problem with a drive that would "disappear" and then reappear later. It wasn't actually mounting either, but `ddrescue` was stopping when the device was disappearing. I was using it under Linux, but the situation is very similar.

I suggest you use **a bit of simple shell programming** and the fact that the drive actually eventually shows up again after a while. In other words, do:

```
while [ 1 ]; do
    ddrescue -v /dev/disk4 image.img logfile
    sleep 3
done
```

This works as follows:

- `ddrescue` is started
- if it stops running, the shell waits for 3 seconds then it starts it again
- `ddrescue` is able to continue because you are making good use of its logging capabilities

After a number of attempts (I think the default is 3 but I may be wrong), `ddrescue` will mark sectors as definitely bad and it will go on reading other parts of the drive. After some hours you will see that `ddrescue` will be done and you can kill the loop with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: I use SATA 2.6 to USB 3.0 converter to rescue my ntfs hdd, but it keeps disappearing until I physically reconnect the USB connector. It also disappears in the `lsblk`, or `lsusb` or `ls /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/` so I don't know how to remount it. The LED of the converter is still on though. I could've done it repeteadly, but it's tedious. Is there any way that your script could be modified to fit in my case?

Comment: @Unknown123 maybe you could try to see if reloading the USB daemon works, but I never tried it.

Answer (score 2):

From [GNU `ddrescue` Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html#Examples):

> Example 6: While rescuing a partition in `/dev/sda1` to the file `hdimage`, `/dev/sda1` disappears from `/dev`.
>
> ```
> ddrescue -f -n /dev/sda1 hdimage mapfile     <-- /dev/sda1 fails here
>   (restart /dev/sda or reboot computer and then repeat the above
>    command as many times as needed until it succeeds)
> ddrescue -d -f -r3 /dev/sda1 hdimage mapfile
> ```

[Andrea Lazzarotto's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1138055/432690) covers the "repeat the above command" part. There is an additional step in the example that uses `-d` switch. [The manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html#Invoking-ddrescue) explains it a little:

> `-d`
>   `--idirect`
>
> Use direct disc access to read from `infile`, bypassing the kernel cache. (Opens the file with the `O_DIRECT` flag). Sector size must be correctly set for this to work. Not all systems support this.

It is advised to further read [the proper section of the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html#Direct-disc-access). From therein:

> Try the `--idirect` option first. If direct disc access is not available in your system, try raw devices. Read your system documentation to find how to bind a raw device to a regular block device. Some OSs provide raw access through especial device names, like `/dev/rdisk`.

MacOS does provide `/dev/rdisk` names. In your question however you use `rdisk` with `dd` but `disk` with `ddrescue`, so it seems to me you may still benefit from the additional step.

Linux users will find `raw` command useful. They should refer to `man raw` and to *Example 2: using a raw device* in [the already mentioned section of the GNU `ddrescue` Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html#Direct-disc-access).